# Please explain to me how these files connect to each other

Tags: ubuntu, shell

So I have two files here. The first one is random.sh, which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

 n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))

 if [[ n -eq 42 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
    exit 1
 fi

 echo "Everything went according to plan"
```

The second one is debug.sh, which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    count=0
    until [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]];
    do
    count=$((count+1))
    ./random.sh &> out.txt
    done

    echo "found error after $count runs"
    cat out.txt
```

When I run command ./debug.sh, the first file will run until n = 42, and then the second file will print the text. But I just don't understand why the code `until [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]];` in the second one, how "$?" can be the result that the first file exit if there is no code to connect these files?

Comment: `debug.sh` is running `random.sh` in a loop until `random.sh` returns a nonzero exit code to `debug.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read `man bash` etc., `$?` the return code of the last program that is executed from the shell script. In your case, that's `./random.sh` inside the loop, and as `until` is part of the loop, the return code gets checked after each call of `./random.sh` when processing the condition for the loop.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks for your answer

Comment: Except in the first iteration of the loop, `$?` comes from the command just before the loop, i.e. the assignment `count=0`, which will likely always succeed (so set `$?` to zero). When comparing `$?` against zero, there's really no reason to explicitly look, that could be written as `while ./random.sh &> out.txt; do  count=$((count+1)); done`. Or if we want the explicit comparison, , as `while ./random.sh &> out.txt; [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; do count=$((count+1)); done`, this being those cases where using two commands in the condition part of the loop is useful. (bar off-by-one in the value of `count`)